# Is the word "other" an adjective that modifies the word "choice" in this question

Tags: adjectives, determiners, parts-of-speech

Is the word "other" an adjective that modifies the word "choice" in the question: "What other choice do we have?"

Comment: Yes, "other" is an adjective modifying "choice".

Comment: Well, it actually modifies the word "options", as written.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional grammar calls it a determiner functioning as an attribute and it modifies the noun *choice* in your question.